# Same Vue code is reactive in one sandbox and not in the other

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I wanted to prepare minimum reproducible sandbox for my issue. I forked my previous sandbox and removed the code that was irrelevant for new case. But one feature stopped working and I have no idea why. The code looks the same and console.log shows the code is updated. Why does it work in one sandbox and does not work in the second?

The original sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-taussig-v8u4b Try to click on some button with numbers, it gets incremented instantly.

Minimized sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-breeze-ejznz. If you click on a button with number, nothing happens until you reload the screen.

I would like to understand this behaviour. I do not see a reason why the same source code behaves differently.

Mutation:

```
SET_VOTE: (state, payload) => {
  console.log("SET_VOTE");
  const { commentId, vote } = payload;
  const comment = state.comments[commentId];
  if (vote === 1) {
    comment.up += 1;
  } else {
    comment.down += 1;
  }
  console.log(comment);
}
```

Action:

```
COMMENT_VOTE: async (context, payload) => {
  console.log("COMMENT_VOTE", payload);
  const mutation = {
    commentId: payload.commentId,
    vote: payload.vote
  };
  context.commit("SET_VOTE", mutation);
}
```

Comment.vue

```
<b-button v-on:click="upvote" class="mr-1">
  {{ comment.up }}
</b-button>

async upvote() {
  await this.$store.dispatch("COMMENT_VOTE", {
    vote: 1,
    commentId: this.comment._id
  });
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about a reactivity again. Use Vue.set to set a new prop in a `comments` state prop:

```
  Vue.set(state.comments, comment._id, comment);
```

instead of

```
  state.comments[comment._id] = comment;
```

Comment: Can you explain why is it not needed in the original sandbox? That is confusing to me. One example does work, the second does not. I do not understand the difference. It should behave the same way everywhere, shouldn't it?

Comment: Your whole comment was not reactive so that's why its prop update was also not reactive

Comment: Ok, I;ll have a look at the original sandbox and will write a new comment here,

Comment: In the original sandbox you store `up` and `down` in the reactive `data` section that's why a reactivity works. Remove {{ mutableUpvotes }} and {{ mutableDownvotes }} from a template and the reactivity will stop working like in the minimized sandbox.

Comment: You are right, it stopped working. My real code works with {{ comment.down }}. Is it because I use the comment in other computed property? I tried in the minified sandbox and it helped partially. I can vote on the first level threads and numbers are increasing. But it has no effect on replies. Which is my original problem I wanted to solve.

Comment: If you add props dynamically and you wish them to be reactive then set them using Vue.set

Answer (score 0):

It finally works. The trick was:

```
data() {
  return {
    commentVotes: this.comment.votes,
  };
computed: {
  upvotes() {
    return this.commentVotes.filter(vote => vote.vote === 1);
  },
  downvotes() {
    return this.commentVotes.filter(vote => vote.vote === -1);
  },
```